# If statement not working while pressing button in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a phone game, where the user guesses the number between 1 and 100. When a button is pressed if the statement should run and do some changes. Nothing althought happens. Why if the statement is not executed when the button pressed?

```
const buttonPressed = () => {

  if ({num} < {randomNum}) {
    message = tooLow

  } else if ({num} > {randomNum}) {
    message = tooHigh

  } else if ({num} === {randomNum}) {
    message= correct
    Alert.alert('You guessed the number in'+{counter}+'guesses')

  }
  counter += 1
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>{message}</View>
        <TextInput 
           style={styles.textinput} 
           keyboardType='numeric' 
           onChangeText={(num) => setNum(num)} 
           value={num}
        />
       <Button onPress={buttonPressed} title="Press me"/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any error in console? Have you tried `onPress={buttonPressed()}`? Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't see declaration of many variables here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make things a bit more React way.
You need to have this `component` an internal state (if you aren't using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/) or any other state management)

Something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    num: 0
  }
}

const setNum = (num) => {
  this.setState({num});
}

const buttonPressed = () => {

  if ({this.props.num} < {randomNum}) {
    message = tooLow
    counter + 1

  } else if ({this.props.num} > {randomNum}) {
    message = tooHigh
    counter + 1

  } else if ({this.props.num} === {randomNum}) {
    counter + 1
    message= correct
    Alert.alert('You guessed the number in'+{counter}+'guesses')

  }
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>{message}</View>
        <TextInput 
           style={styles.textinput} 
           keyboardType='numeric' 
           onChangeText={(num) => this.setNum(num)} 
           value={this.props.num}
        />
       <Button onPress={buttonPressed} title="Press me"/>
    </View>
  );
}
```